# Lotus Notes 8.5 Send and File - Collapse Folders?

Tags: lotus-notes

When I want to "send and file" an email in Lotus Notes 8.5, all my folders are expanded, which means I have to scroll through several dozen sometimes to get to the one I want. Is there a way to make the folders collapsed in the view when I want to send and file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no setting to open this view collapsed. But you can Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> when the dialog is open. This collapses the complete folder tree. Probably this is a workaround you can use.

Comment: Learning about shift + and shift - has made Notes so much more usable for me. One of the upgrades we did changed the default behavior of a bunch of databases from always collapsed to always expanded.